# Is it possible to set the date on a Linux machine to the year 2040?

Tags: linux, date

I need to be able to set the date on Ubuntu (8.04.4 LTS) to the year 2040 (to test something that isn't relevant to this question).  Is that possible?

I can run:

```
$ sudo date -s "15 JAN 2038 18:00:00"
Fri Jan 15 18:00:00 PST 2038
```

...but:

```
$ sudo date -s "15 JAN 2039 18:00:00"
date: invalid date `15 JAN 2039 18:00:00'
```

Is the limit somewhere in 2038 (or prior to Jan. 15, 2039)?  Does this change with different versions of Linux?

Comment: You've done well, creating two new (and perfectly valid) tags for one question. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In systems that represent time as a 32bit interger, no. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem for more details. Per that article, the latest time that most systems can represent is 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038.

Note that most 64bit systems already use 64 bits to store time, so this won't be a problem once you upgrade (which you should do anyway so you can use all that RAM you bought in your new fast machine).

Comment: +1, I hope there aren't many 32 bit systems left when 2038 rolls around...

Comment: @Chris, hope all you like but just remember there are still a great many 8 and 16 bit (non-PC) systems in use today, so don't expect too much.